Do I need interior drains or is grading sufficient?
I have some water issues in my house. I have consulted two separate waterproofing companies. One company is very large while the other is a small business.
Before talking about the proposed solutions, I’ll describe the problem. There are three main problems. They are all in the basement.

In my storage room where my sump pump sits there is a crack in the bottom corner of the wall next to the sump pump. Fortunately the water flows right to the sump pump.

In my family room there is a wall that gets moist. I believe this is because of the concrete walkway sloping toward the house.

In a bed room, the wall also gets moist. It doesn’t get as moist anymore since I replaced my hvac.


Now the for proposals.
The guy from smaller company suggested to replace the walkway and grade it properly. He will then add a new sump pump and move the pipe it connects to away from the house. He will also rip out the inside walls clean and spray. He said he will patch some cracks.
The guy from the bigger company. Will also replace the sump pump and rip out the bad walls and spray. However, he didn’t say anything about redirecting the pipe.
He is suggesting to jackhammer the inside floors. He said he would add two drains under the floor. He said that the issue isn’t outside.
He says grading makes little difference. The soil will get soaked regardless. The inside underground drain will move the water out. Also the moisture isn’t from the water directly it’s from the evaporation. The water condenses on the wall.

Grading helps.  If sealing/water proofing the basement walls that is done from the outside.  Adding pipes/drains to the floor might help also.

He is wrong about grading.  What do you mean "rip out the bad walls?"  That sounds expensive.  What is the construction of the wall(s) in question?

@Huesmann they will rip out the damaged inside drywall and any rotted wood. They will then clean and spray if there is mold.

Oh.  You're gonna have to replace any rotted interior wall material anyway.  If the moisture is from condensation, you have an insulation problem.  Condensation only happens when warm moist air comes into contact with cold surfaces.
